# How to add translations of photo names?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

Adding one photo. The name of the photo is example.jpg.

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/front/homepage/example.jpg') }}" alt="example">
```

Depending on the language, it needs to display a different name of the photo on the page. This cannot cause a photo display error.
In Polish, the name should look like this: example-polish.jpg

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/front/homepage/example-polish.jpg') }}" alt="example">
```

I don't want to duplicate photos because it is a poor solution in terms of memory on the server.

How can I rename photos using translations in symfony?

Comment: You want "example.jpg" and "example-polish.jpg" to be the same file, render the same image? Or you want to actually have two different images, one for "en" and one for "pl", and show the appropriate image for each locale?

Comment: It has to be the same rendered image with a different file name, the client really cares about it, but I think it's impossible

Comment: It might be possible with some server tweaks, but it's generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but the file content stays the same right?

If it is for SEO purposes you should use the `alt`-attribute for the translation

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/front/homepage/example.jpg') }}" alt="{{ 'translation'|trans }}">
```

or use `<figure>` with `<figcaption>`

```
<figure>
    <img src="{{ asset('images/front/homepage/example.jpg') }}" alt="{{ 'translation'|trans }}">
    <figcaption>{{ 'translation'|trans }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```